# Attempt to read property "menus" on null

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

when i run laravel project on my computer after doing php artisan serve as soon as it login it shows error "Attempt to read property "menus" on null"

Please help me

```
 @foreach ($specials->menus as $menu)
                    <div class="max-w-xs mx-4 mb-2 rounded-lg shadow-lg">
                        <img class="w-full h-48" src="{{ Storage::url($menu->image) }}" alt="Image" />
                        <div class="px-6 py-4">
                            <h4 class="mb-3 text-xl font-semibold tracking-tight text-green-600 uppercase">
                                {{ $menu->name }}</h4>
                            <p class="leading-normal text-gray-700">{{ $menu->description }}.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex items-center justify-between p-4">
                            <span class="text-xl text-green-600">${{ $menu->price }}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
```

welcomecontroller.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Menu extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'price', 'description', 'image'];

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'category_menu');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code where you are passing $specials to view and returning it.

Comment: $specials = Category::where('name', 'specials')->first();

        return view('welcome', compact('specials'));

Comment: if you dd $specials in controller before return, what do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you forgot to initialize `$specials`, it is null, that's why you get the error.

Could you try to use `dd` before `foreach` statement, so we can see it's content?

```
{{ dd($specials) }}
```

UPDATE:

```
@if(!is_null($specials))
 @foreach ($specials->menus as $menu)
                    <div class="max-w-xs mx-4 mb-2 rounded-lg shadow-lg">
                        <img class="w-full h-48" src="{{ Storage::url($menu->image) }}" alt="Image" />
                        <div class="px-6 py-4">
                            <h4 class="mb-3 text-xl font-semibold tracking-tight text-green-600 uppercase">
                                {{ $menu->name }}</h4>
                            <p class="leading-normal text-gray-700">{{ $menu->description }}.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex items-center justify-between p-4">
                            <span class="text-xl text-green-600">${{ $menu->price }}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
@else
<div>no item was found</div>
@endif
```

Comment: its work. but it look messy

Comment: null // resources\views/welcome.blade.php

Comment: I see you use `$specials = Category::where('name', 'specials')->first();` to get specials, maybe you have no rows in database that's why you get the error. Try to use the code I added to my response to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with this line of code (from the comments):

```
$specials = Category::where('name', 'specials')->first();
```

`->first();` can return `null`, so when you use it later as `$specials->menus`, it *can* be `null->menus`, which is not valid.

You can use `->firstOrFail()` to trigger a 404 in the event `$specials` results in `null`, or `@foreach($specials->menus ?? [] as $menu)` to short-circuit your `foreach()` with an empty array if `$specials` is `null`:

In your `Controller`:

```
$specials = Category::where('name', 'specials')->firstOrFail();

return view('welcome', compact('specials'));
```

OR

In your `View`:

```
@foreach($specials->menus ?? [] as $menu)
  ...
@endforeach
```

Either case will properly handle your "unsafe" code (unsafe meaning functional, but possible for unhandled errors, like `null->menus`, etc.) and either trigger a `404` before the view is rendered, or perform a `foreach()` on an empty array, which does nothing.